# Regular Expression If 2nd parameter is Enrollment

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have below response

```
{
      "id": "3452",
      "enrollable_id": "3452",
      "enrollable_type": "Enrollment"
}
{
      "id": "3453",
      "enrollable_id": "3453",
      "enrollable_type": "Task"
}
{
      "id": "3454",
      "enrollable_id": "3454",
      "enrollable_type": "Enrollment"
}
{
      "id": "3455",
      "enrollable_id": "3455",
      "enrollable_type": "Task"
}
```

I would like to get id [3452 and 3454] only if enrollable_type= Enrollment. This is for jmeter regex extractor so it would be great if I can just use one liner regex to fetch 3452 and 3454.

Comment: Isn't there some way for you to parse the JSON and then process it as an array of objects?

Comment: See http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e1

Comment: i can use json extractor but it will get me all the ids. I just need specific ones

Comment: Actually you can use json extractor and apply condition to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract some value from JSON using JsonPath with != condition in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002115/extract-some-value-from-json-using-jsonpath-with-condition-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx you are looking for is:

```
_id":\s*"([^"]+(?=[^\0}]+_type":\s*"E))
```

[Try it online!](http://www.regexr.com/3uhrg)

---

**Explanation**

```
_id":\s*"                                Finds the place where the enrollment_id is
          [^"]+(?=                       Matches the ID if:
                  [^\0}]+_type":\s*      Finds the place where enrollable_type is
                                   "E    Checks if the enrollable type begins with an uppercase E
                                     )   End if
         (                            )  Captures the ID
```

It's important to note that this RegEx will **match** on valid *people* and **capture** the valid *ID*. This means you will need to get each match's capture rather than just getting each match.

---

### Disclaimer

The above RegEx contains backslashes, which you will need to escape if using the RegEx as a string literal.

This is the RegEx with all necessary-to-escape characters escaped:

```
_id":\\s*"([^"]+(?=[^\\0}]+_type":\\s*"E))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a bad idea to parse structured data with just a regex, but if you're intent on going this route then here you go:

```
"(\d+)"\s*,\s*(?="enrollable_type":\s*"Enrollment")
```

This assumes that `entrollable_type` always follows `enrollable_id` and that everything is quoted consistently with a little allowance for variance in white space.  You should be able to handle a little more variance if necessary, such as if you're unsure if can depend on keys or data being quoted (`["']?`).  However, if you can depend on the order of the properties (such as if they type comes before id) then you should abandon using a regex.

**Here's a sample working in JavaScript**

```js
const text = `{ "id": "3452", "enrollable_id": "3452", "enrollable_type": "Enrollment" } { "id": "3453", "enrollable_id": "3453", "enrollable_type": "Task" } { "id": "3454", "enrollable_id": "3454", "enrollable_type": "Enrollment" } { "id": "3455", "enrollable_id": "3455", "enrollable_type": "Task" }`;

const re = /"(\d+)"\s*,\s*(?="enrollable_type":\s*"Enrollment")/g;
var match; 
while(match = re.exec(text)) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: I need this regex in Java :( . Javascript regex didn't work. I use https://regex101.com/

Comment: Just escape the string.  This regex is simple enough it'll work in pretty much any regex flavor.  I just provided the JavaScript so you could see it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your response seems to be a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) one (however it's malformed). If this is the case and it's really JSON - I would recommend going for [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead as regular expressions are fragile, sensitive to markup change, new lines, order of elements, etc. while JSON Extractor looks only into the content.

The relevant [JSON Path query](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) would be something like:

```
$..[?(@.enrollable_type == 'Enrollment')].enrollable_id
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Extractor Conditional Select]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data in 2 ways

1. Using [Json Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor).

To extract data using json extractor response data should follow json syntax rules,

To extract data  use the following JSON path in json extractor

```
$..[?(@.enrollable_type=="Enrollment")].id
```

and use match no `-1`  as shown below

[image]

2. To extract data using [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) use the following regex

`id": "(.+?)",\s*(.+?)\s*"enrollable_type": "Enrollment`

```
template : $1$2$3$4$
Match no -1
```

as shown below

[image]

you can see the variables stored using debug sampler
[image]

More information

[extract variables](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)